# Adding Field in Qweb table of odoo 8

Tags: odoo

There is field account.analytic.line and I want it to be displayed in qweb report.
   * Move Line in qweb report

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqXnW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Any code sharing?

I think you have to add new field to your xml file like the others debit, credit, balance for example. If they belong to base addon you should look at related base addon how they did it. But first check py file is value exists?

and look at https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/qweb.html